# Symfony2 routing error No route found for "GET /query"

Tags: php, symfony, routes, http-status-code-404

I'm having problems with creating new routes in Symfony2 v2.3. I get error message

```
No route found for "GET /query"
404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
1 linked Exception: ResourceNotFoundException »
```

I've searched for solutions but none of it worked... I even crashed a server experimenting with appDevUrlGenerator.php and appDevUrlMatcher.php.

So, here is part of the code in my DefaultController:

```
public function queryAction(Request $request)
{
    $repository=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('TestFirstBundle:UserTicket');


    $lists = $repository->findBystatus('Open');


    if (!$lists) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'No forms found '
        );
    }

    return $this->render('TestFirstBundle:Default:query.html.twig', array(
        'lists' => $lists,

    ));
```

my routing.yml inside bundle:

```
test_First_homepage:
path:     /dipl
defaults: { _controller: TestFirstBundle:Default:index }


test_First_submit:
path:     /subm
defaults: { _controller: TestFirstBundle:Default:submit }

test_First_query:
path:     /query
defaults: { _controller: TestFirstBundle:Default:query }
```

and app/config/routing.yml (I've put the same thing in app/config/routing_dev.yml)

```
test_first:
resource: "@TestFirstBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
prefix:   /
```

I'll just add that /dipl and /subm routes work perfectly and they are connected to indexAction and submitAction where I've put my form (which redirects after submitting form). Also, if I comment out my real indexAction and just rename queryAction to indexAction it works perfectly on /dipl url, and does exactly the right thing as queryAction should do. So I'm guessing that there is a problem in connection between queryAction and /query url. But when I run

```
   php app/console router:match /query
```

I get the correct thing:

```
[router] Route "test_First_query"
Name         test_First_query
Path         /query
Host         ANY
Scheme       ANY
Method       ANY
Class        Symfony\Component\Routing\Route
Defaults     _controller:           Test\FirstBundle\Controller\DefaultController::queryAction
Requirements NO CUSTOM
Options      compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler
Path-Regex   #^/query$#s
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought maybe it was a reserved route or something, however I'm on symfony 2.3 as well and this quick test worked fine:

```
/**
 * @Route("/query", name="query")
 */
public function queryAction()
{
    return new Response('query');
}
```

I get a response back OK. So it's not that. It might be that you have some sort of alias or resource configured under /query outside of Symfony2 (in your HTTP server maybe?) that is interfering with this route somehow?

Comment: I tried with random names for that action/route/url and it's the same no matter what I name it. Also, I'm running localhost and this is my first project